# Android CheckedTextView checkbox UI doesn't refresh until next click

Tags: java, android, mobile

I have a CheckedTextView and the checkbox doesn't refresh until the next click.

My activity is extending Activity instead of ListActivity because I have a listView and button in the layout.

I'm setting the ListView ItemClickListener as follows. The problem is the checkbox doesn't appear as "checked" until a click another item. So I click row 3, then I click row 4 and row 3 highlights. Click row 10, and row 4 finally highlights. When I say "highlight" I mean the checkbox turns green.

I'm not sure what method needs to be called to force the checkbox to redraw/update itself. I've tried calling cbview.refreshDrawableState(); and cbview.getCheckMarkDrawable().invalidateSelf(); after setChecked but they don't seem to do anything.

```
    listView
        .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                CheckedTextView cbview = (CheckedTextView)view;
                boolean checked = cbview.isChecked();
                cbview.setChecked(!checked);
                Log.d("Test", "clicked:" + position + " : " + id);
            }

        });
```

UPDATED: ANSWER:

had to make my adapter final:

```
    final ArrayAdapter<MyOption> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyOption>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, options);
```

and then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in the onItemClick:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,  int position, long id) {                 
                CheckedTextView cbview = (CheckedTextView)view;
                boolean checked = cbview.isChecked();
                cbview.setChecked(!checked);
                Log.d("Test", "clicked:" + position + " : " + id + ":" + cbview.isChecked());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                 
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tryed

```
    listViewAdapater.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I believe that calling `setChecked()` redraws the `view` which is what calling `invalidate()` does. Same with `setText()` on a `TextView`

Comment: how about this.. ?
     `listViewAdapater.notifyDataSetChanged();`